# I lost 3 ETH transfering from Ether.li to Poloniex

Tags: poloniex, ether.li

I need help (please, please, please) for understanding what's happens.

1 - From Ether.li I did a first attempt for transfer 3 eth to poloniex. But susprisly, the operation was made with 0 eth. Still 3 eth in the ether.li wallet.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x877a797e27cfa4ea7129fba344c7998e97949327aff19f8e062fe3b29d3580ff

2- I tried to transfer again next day, and in this time it was apparently good, because my balance in ether.li was 0 eth.
But now I can see there is 3 internal transactions, being the first of them my wallet in poloniex, and the others wallets of poloniex, like hot wallets or similar. 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb3b9ccf5c592926eeb8a1822b14d4bcf762f6b0b6fd9defe692f988746e29415

3- Here is my contract [0x7c7e907032d95598f5dbbe11c72612e9f7f7ef18](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7c7e907032d95598f5dbbe11c72612e9f7f7ef18)

4- If I go to internal transactions in my contract, I can see  the transfer of the 3 eth the wallet on polloniex.

Things I already did:

- 6 tickets to Poloniex. They only answered the first, like automatic answer (very fast, 1 second delay) saying they were having problems of delay in this momments with eth, and please wait.

  - Email to poloniex
  - 3 attemps to chat with a moderator in the chat of poloniex.
  - Twitter poloniex.

  Also...

  - Email to ether.li
  - Twitter to creators of ether.li (as they ask for it in the contact page)

Also...

- Ask in forums for understand what happens, and where can be my eth.

I know I'm like an "ant" in this world of criptos, lot of newbies here asking for same problems. Please, I really would appreciate if someone can bring me a little bit of light.

Thank you

JAKE: I FACE THIS ISSUE AS WELL AND LOTS OF OTHERS DO TOO. IT WOULD BE LOVELY IF THIS QUESTION WOULD BE ANSWERED.

Comment: You should try also reddit. But if the addresses are correct and you have follow the proper procedure then you should be ok. Sometimes they take way too long to repply, just keep insisting. Try to gather all information possible. But IMHO this is not the place to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: Your [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb3b9ccf5c592926eeb8a1822b14d4bcf762f6b0b6fd9defe692f988746e29415) indicates that your funds where moved to Poloniex. Get in touch with them.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer. Poloniex is a bad headache, after 20 tickets in 3 months they don't answer.